# WebView goBack: breaks custom JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webkit, webview

I have a Cocoa app with an embedded `WebView`. I've set up my delegate to respond to a number of custom Objective-C functions that can be called from JavaScript. For example, in JavaScript I will be able to call something like `console.log()`

I set the delegate as follows:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {    
    [self.webView.windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"console"];
}
```

Now when I navigate to another page and then use the back button (via `WebView goBack:`), the above method is not called and I can't set the `console` object.

However, the JavaScript object still exists (`typeof(console)` returns `object`), but calling any function on it does not have any effect.

First of all, does anybody know why `didClearWindowObject:` is not called when I invoke `goBack:`? Any suggestions how I can debug the JavaScript object?